# WPF, possibly ribbon control: Adding icon to title bar

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, ribboncontrolslibrary

I believe that the little icon in the title bar in the image below is added using a ribbon control? I've been googling for the last while and I'm not getting much help.

There's a [WPF ribbon control library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en) from Microsoft, but the same from that does not set anything in the title bar.

I've also found a microsoft [shell library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell) which integrates some windows 7 bits into wpf and allows you to fiddle with the chrome. It hasn't seen updates in a year, so not sure if it's current yet.

Any ideas?

**Related question** Does it only work on Windows 7? I don't have any XP machines to see what Office 2010 looks like. I'd prefer a XP/Windows 7 WPF solution if possible.

[image: How do I do this?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called the [Quick Access Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx) and there is an example at the end of this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonquickaccesstoolbar.aspx).

It should work the same on both XP and Windows 7 (and Vista for that matter).

Answer (score 3):

That area is known as the Quick Access ToolBar as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940502(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm not sure on the specifics in regards to the Ribbon control library that you referenced, but we are using one from Actipro and it works great and both xp and win7 are supported.

Comment: FYI, your link is for the MFC Ribbon control, not the WPF one ;-)

Comment: My google skills completely failed me yesterday!! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though :)